# Agora Flutter RtcEngineEventHandler.joinChannelSuccess doesn't get triggered but no error returned

Tags: flutter, agora.io

`joinChannelSuccess` is supposed to execute once the local user joins the channel successfully, but now this event NEVER gets triggered.
And also Agora isn't returning any error. Using agora_rtc_engine: ^5.2.0 with Flutter.

Comment: Any solution here?

Comment: sorry, I didn't find a solution at that time